# focus two application in same time on windows

Tags: windows

Is there any way to give focus to two application in same time in windows.

They need to be controlled by two input type (one can be mouse, other can be keyboard, or both can be controlled with two keyboards). On windows only one window (application) can have focus and you can send input to one of window.

Comment: Doesn't that conflict with the concept of "having the focus"?

Comment: I believe the scientific term for multiple focus points is "aberration". More seriously, it looks like what you are looking for is something like Multipoint Server.

Comment: It's gonna be messy - the cursor is hardware-generated and you would need two graphics cards, (and other gunge/drivers).  Rather you tried it than me...

Comment: think about I put two window on two screen with laptop seperated desktop feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Focus is used for controlling which process and or scope has user input.  It's associated with the message pump and follows focus. All user events pertinent to the application are trapped by the system and sent to the application that has focus. The best you can hope for is something that will take focus and redirect according to input type.